# Reading grib file without extension using Xarray

Tags: grib, xarray

Is it possible to read a file without an extension from Xarray and let Xarray infer the correct datatype?

**Context**: I downloaded files with `.Z` compression from https://data.eol.ucar.edu/. An example file name would be `ST4.2002010100.06h.Z` Since, I'm using windows, I used the 7Zip utility to extract the archive. Since the extracted file doesn't contain any extension (`ST4.2002010100.06h`), I cannot open the extracted file using Xarray; Xarray raises this  ValueError.

```
ValueError: did not find a match in any of xarray's currently installed IO backends ['netcdf4', 'h5netcdf', 'scipy', 'cfgrib', 'pydap', 'zarr']. Consider explicitly selecting one of the installed engines via the ``engine`` parameter, or installing additional IO dependencies, see:
```

If I add an extension to the file (i.e. raname 'ST4.2002010100.06h' to 'ST4.2002010100.06h.grb'). X array will open it. From documentation of the data, some files are grib2 and some are in grib1. I'm not sure if adding `.grb` would be an ideal approach in this case.

Is it possible to read a file without an extension from Xarray and let Xarray infer the correct datatype?

An example file here: https://www.dropbox.com/t/RgGeyWURlGaTRSlr

Comment: Have you tried following the advice of the error and using the `engine` parameter, perhaps with `cfgrib` as a value?

Comment: @alphabetasoup Thank you. using engine =`cfgrib` worked.